# Changing Background/Text Color of a Search Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search bar in my navigation bar (using Bootstrap):

```
<li>
    <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="search-query offset1" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</li>
```

I want to change the default background color and text color, so I've implemented the following CSS:

```
input .search-query {
    background-color:#f47443;
    color:white;
}
```

Yet the colors remain the same -- black and white. Is there something special about form/input background colors and font colors that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
input.search-query {
    /* css */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SYCwT/).

Without the space it selects an `input` element with a class of `search-query`; *with* a space separating the terms `input` and `.search-query` the browser is looking inside the `input` element for a *descendant* element with the `search-query` class.

Incidentally, the selector as you wrote it:

```
input .search-query {
    /* css */
}
```

could *never* match any element, since an `input` (as are `img` elements) void elements in that they cannot contain descendant elements or even text.

References:

- [CSS Selectors (Level 3), W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: Also, make sure that the `.offset1` class doesn't set these properties, otherwise, in the `input .search-query`, you will have to add `!important;` at the end of each instructions to override. Or don't apply `offset1` to your input and add the instructions from `offset1` to `input.search` except for `color` and `background-color` if there are ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
input .search-query {
    background-color:#f47443;
    color:white;
}
```

>

```
input.search-query {
    background-color:#f47443;
    color:white;
}
```

Remove space.